# Is it possible to work with DSD audio on MATLAB?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, sound, dsp-core

*Just for starters: I am very new to audio processing*

I was looking for audio data that is in 1-bit format and I stumbled upon DSD. From what I was able to read it is old but kind of controversial format among audio engineers. It samples in binary format but with very high sampling rate.

But when I tried to see if there some samples available that I can download and play with in MATLAB I didn't find anything.

Can someone please explain me if it just 0's and 1's then why no sample audios or information regarding it's compatibility with MATLAB is not available?

Comment: DSD is a fairly old format and you won't find a lot of tools for it. You can buy DSD tracks at hdtracks.com. There are some DSD to PCM converters available, e.g. https://samplerateconverter.com/educational/dsd-converter . If you want to do this Matlab, you'll probably have to write your own. It's a simple delta modulation, so it's not all that difficult to do.

Comment: Actually I am trying to find audio data that is present in 1-bit format. Do you have any idea if there is a way of representing raw audio data in binary form?

Comment: If you are looking for a 1-btt representations, DSD is a good candidate. You can certainly buy a track or two, there are not all that expensive. Not sure someone offers them for free. Standard format for audio is PCM. The converter that I linked can turn a PCM file into a DSD file as well, so that's another way of making one